# Linear combination of Payoffs using Black-Scholes

Tags: black-scholes, mathematics, finance-mathematics

Write the payoffs in Figure 3.8 as linear combination of call options and derive a closed form formula for the Black-Scholes price, the Delta, and the Gamma of them. All the Greeks of the option are also linear combination of these call option Greeks. For instance, $$\Delta(t,S) = \Phi(d_1(\tau,K_1,S)) - \Phi(d_1(\tau,K_2,S)) - \Phi(d_1(\tau,K_3,S)) + \Phi(d_1(\tau,K_4,S))$$[image]

Partial Solution: For the strangle we have a pay off of $$(K - S_T)_{+} + (S_T - K)_{+}$$ Therefore the closed form solution of B-S price of option is $$V(\tau,S) = P(\tau,K,S) + C(\tau,K,S)$$ and the delta of the position is $$\Delta(\tau,S) = -\Phi(-d_1(\tau,K,S)) + \Phi(d_1(\tau,K,S))$$ Finally our gamma for this position is $$\Gamma(\tau,S) = \frac{\Phi'(d_1(\tau,K,S)) + \Phi'(d_1(\tau,K,S))}{S\sigma \sqrt{\tau}}$$

I guess my professor made a mistake in regards to the B-S closed form price: for the strange it is $$V(\tau,S) = (-S_0\Phi(-d_1) + e^{-rT}K\Phi(-d_2)) + (S_0\Phi(d_1) - e^{-rT}K\Phi(d_2))$$ and similar for the straddle

where $\tau = T - t$ not sure why we use $\tau$ any explanation of that would be great.

Comment: I think the question wants you to replicate the payoffs with some payoff options, only different in strike. You can easily do that by long and short position.

Comment: What are the values for  the points intercept the X and Y axis?

Comment: One thing that is confusing is that the LEFT payoff is a straddle, the RIGHT is a strangle; labels are reversed. Also, these diagrams represent combinations of calls AND PUTS, not just "call options". So the question is somewhat misphrased.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that my teacher has a lot of errors in his problems his exam questions are usually not solvable and he can't even answer his own questions

Comment: @Gordon I made an edit to the post

Comment: The put option delta is incorrect. It should be $-\Phi(-d_1)$.

Comment: @Gordon please see changes, am I correct now? and do you have any idea why the professor uses $\tau$?

Comment: Your gamma is still wrong. See my answer below.

Comment: @Gordon Ok I fixed my gamma, what does $\Phi'$ mean I am about confused if this was a numerical solution how would one find $\Phi'$?

Comment: @Gordon can you reply to my question in case you missed it?

Comment: No, still not. $[-\Phi(-d_1(\tau,K,S))]'=\Phi'(d_1(\tau,K,S))$.

Comment: are you stating my gamma is still wrong?

Comment: @Gordon I am not sure if it is me but I do not fully understand you sometimes. In the other post you say I am wrong with the way I wrote the closed form solution of B-S price. Then in this post you say I am right but my gamma is wrong, which one is it? I just want to know what I have to do make this correct as I have an exam tomorrow

Comment: Here I say your delta and gamma are correct. But I didn't say your bs formula  is correct as you didn't provide a bs formula.

Comment: I see, let me edit it through what you have done below one moment

Comment: @Gordon I made an edit, is that somewhat correct now?

Comment: @Gordon: I admire your patience.

Comment: @Gordon I attempted to rewrite the B-S formula for the bear spread is that the way it is suppose to be written?

Comment: The put price is still wrong.

Comment: @Gordon I see that now, just some sign changes that needed to be made is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you for being patient with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express such payoff in mathematical form, it is better to use indicator functions. I assume that the bottom of graphs (i.e., the vertex for the left one and the bottom segment for the right side one) represents zero.

For the left-hand one, the payoff is given by
\begin{align*}
(K-S_T)\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K} + (S_T-K)\pmb{1}_{S_T \ge K} = (K-S_T)^+ + (S_T-K)^+,
\end{align*}
that is, a straddle that involves both a European call and put with the same strike price and maturity date.

For the right-hand one,  the payoff is given by
\begin{align*}
(K_1-S_T)\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_1} + (S_T-K_2)\pmb{1}_{S_T \ge K_2} = (K_1-S_T)^+ + (S_T-K_2)^+,\tag{1}
\end{align*}
that is, a strangle that involves both a European call and put with the same  maturity date, but different strikes.

For valuation, as an example, let's consider (1). According to the Black-Scholes' formula, the value of Payoff (1) is given by
\begin{align*}
V=\Big[K_1 e^{-rT} \Phi(-d_2^1) - S_0 \Phi(-d_1^1)\Big] + \Big[S_0 \Phi(d_1^2) - K_2 e^{-rT} \Phi(d_2^2)\Big],
\end{align*}
where the first term is the value of the put option payoff $(K_1-S_T)^+$ and the second is the value of the call option payoff $(S_T-K_2)^+$. Here,
\begin{align*}
d_1^1 &= \frac{\ln \frac{S_0}{K_1} + (r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}},\\
d_2^1 &= d_1^1 - \sigma \sqrt{T},\\
d_1^2 &= \frac{\ln \frac{S_0}{K_2} + (r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}},\\
d_2^2 &= d_1^2 - \sigma \sqrt{T}.\\
\end{align*}
The delta hedge ratio is the sum of deltas of the first put option and the second call options, that is,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial S_0} &= -\Phi(-d_1^1) + \Phi(d_1^2)\\
&=\Phi(d_1^1) + \Phi(d_1^2) - 1,
\end{align*}
and the gamma hedge ratio is the sum of gammas of the first put option and the second call options, that is,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_0^2} &= \frac{\Phi'(d_1^1)}{S_0\sigma \sqrt{T}}+ \frac{\Phi'(d_1^2)}{S_0\sigma \sqrt{T}}\\
&=\frac{\Phi'(d_1^1) + \Phi'(d_1^2)}{S_0\sigma \sqrt{T}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Does this answer provide the  "Black-Scholes price, the Delta, and the Gamma of them"?

Comment: Those are two vanilla options. You can then compute the price for each of them using Black-scholes' formula. Consequently the delta and gamma can be computed.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand completely, unless you think I simply can't see it could you edit your answer to include the Black-Scholes formula and how we compute the delta and gamma?

Comment: It is just a sum of two options, please try.

Comment: When you say it is the sum of 2 options that sounds like the payoff of the option portfolio. I know how to compute delta if we are given the parameters: interest rate, volatility, price of stock, strike price. But I am not sure how to compute gamma

Comment: It is a portfolio. Gamma is the second derivative w.r.t the spot. The second derivative,  w.r.t the spot, of a sum is the sum of the second derivatives,  w.r.t the spot.

Comment: Ok, but without numbers how can we apply gamma, from my understanding $\Gamma(T,S) = \frac{1}{S\sigma \sqrt{T}}\Phi'(d_1)$? I am sorry but I still do not understand how to apply this to the problem nor for Delta for that matter

Comment: I made an edit to the post please see if I am on the right track and if you can answer the inquiries I have.

Comment: Your notation although I am sure correct is confusing for me to understand, if you can, look at the partial solution I made: am I on the right track or no?

Comment: I used the superscript 1 or 2 to distinguish for $K_1$ and $K_2$.