# Linear combination of payoffs of bull and bear spreads

Tags: options, option-pricing, mathematics, finance-mathematics

Write the following payoffs as linear combination of call options
with different strikes and possibly some cash and give the closed form formula for them.[image]

Attempted solution: The payoff for the bear spread is $$(K_2 - S_T)^{+} - (K_1 - S_T)^{+}$$ Therefore our closed form solution for the B-S price is $$V(\tau,S) = P(\tau,K_2,S) - P(\tau,K_1,S) $$ The payoff for the bull spread is $$(S_T - K_1)^{+} - (S_T - K_2)^{+}$$ Therefore our closed form solution for the B-S price is $$V(\tau,S) = C(\tau,K_1,S) - C(\tau,K_2,S)$$

I was told the closed form B-S price is incorrect but my professors lecture notes say otherwise:

[image: professors example]

Comment: Not yet correct. Write each term using  the BS formula.

Comment: What part is not correct, I don't understand your statement

Comment: @Gordon I made an edit, is my solution correct now?

Comment: No. Please double check what the BS formula look like. Your formula is not the BS formula at all. Can you please write out the formulas for payoffs $(S_T-K_1)^+$ and $(S_T-K_2)^+$. Any book has the formula or you can google it

Comment: In addition, I have specifically written out the formula in my answer to your question http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24927/linear-combination-of-payoffs-using-black-scholes.

Comment: The closed for solution to the B-S price is explicitly just as how I defined it, and the example my professor has in his lecture notes has it the very same way, I will post a picture to it now to show you

Comment: That is not the bs formula . please Google to find the correct one.

Comment: Are you stating that my professors example the closed form B-S price is wrong then? If so then I will take your word for it as he has made mistakes many times in the past

Comment: @Gordon Is my professors formula wrong?

Comment: Can you Google bs and provide me a link?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model

Comment: @Gordon I provided you a link the formula is denoted under the title B-S formula

Comment: I made some addition to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we assume that the bottom is zero and the top is $K_2-K_1$. Then, in mathematical form, the ${\color{blue} {blue}}$ option payoff is given by
\begin{align*}
& \ (K_2-K_1)\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_1} + (K_2-S_T)\pmb{1}_{K_1 < S_T \le K_2} \\
=& \ (K_2-K_1)\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_1} + (K_2-S_T)\left(\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_2} - \pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_1}\right)\\
=& \ (K_2-S_T)\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_2}+\big[(K_2-K_1) - (K_2-S_T) \big]\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_1}\\
=& \ (K_2-S_T)^+ - (K_1-S_T)^+ ,\tag{1}
\end{align*}
that is, a put spread. Note that, this option can also be replicated with a zero-coupon bond and a call spread:
\begin{align*}
& \ (K_2-K_1)\pmb{1}_{S_T \le K_1} + (K_2-S_T)\pmb{1}_{K_1 < S_T \le K_2} \\
=& \ (K_2-K_1)\left(1-\pmb{1}_{S_T \ge K_1} \right)+ (K_2-S_T)\left(\pmb{1}_{S_T \ge K_1} - \pmb{1}_{S_T \ge K_2}\right)\\
=& \ (K_2-K_1) + \big[(K_2-S_T) - (K_2-K_1) \big]\pmb{1}_{S_T \ge K_1} +(S_T-K_2)\pmb{1}_{S_T \ge K_2}\\
=& \ (K_2-K_1) +(S_T-K_2)^+ - (S_T-K_1)^+.
\end{align*}

For the ${\color{red} {red}}$ option payoff, the approach is the same.

> EDIT:

The price of Payoff (1) is given by
\begin{align*}
put(K_2) - put(K_1).
\end{align*}
Note that this price is 'not necessarily the Black-Scholes' price', as Black-Scholes' price has a particular form. In particular, in the Black-Scholes' pricing framework, we assume that the underlying equity price process $\{S_t \mid t \ge 0\}$ satisfies, under the risk-neutral probability measure, an SDE of the form
\begin{align*}
dS_t/S_t = rdt + \sigma dW_t,
\end{align*}
where $\{W_t \mid t \ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then,
\begin{align*}
put(K_1) &= K_1 e^{-rT} \Phi(-d_2^1) - S_0 \Phi(-d_1^1)\\
put(K_2) &= K_2 e^{-rT} \Phi(-d_2^2) - S_0 \Phi(-d_1^2),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
d_1^1 &= \frac{\ln \frac{S_0}{K_1} + (r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}},\\
d_2^1 &= d_1^1 - \sigma \sqrt{T},\\
d_1^2 &= \frac{\ln \frac{S_0}{K_2} + (r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}},\\
d_2^2 &= d_1^2 - \sigma \sqrt{T}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I made an edit to my post, can you check to see if I am correct?

Comment: Also, I liked how you included the replication do you have a reference material to know how to replicate all of the different option strategies i.e. bull spread, bear spread, straddle, strangle, etc...?

Comment: No reference. But the technique is the same. First express it using indicator functions and then decompose.

Answer (score 0):

Think like this:

1. Start with a long call option for K1. This would give you a payoff reflected at K1.
2. Short some cash to move the payoff vertically down.
3. Short a call option for K2. The payoff of this short option will offset the payoff of your long call option for `>K2`.

You can visualize this portfolio should give you the payoff for bull spread call. The other payoff is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the blue case, bear spread call.
Since it starts with a constant, then you need some cash.
Also we need to assume, say bear call spread, the constant parts are $(K_1 + K_2)/2$ and $-(K_1 + K_2)/2$ at both ends (technically makes the slope be 1 in middle of the function).

Consider the call option as following
$$
C_{\text{bear}} = \frac{(K_2 - K_1)}{2} - (S_T - K_1)_+ + (S_T - K_2)_+
$$

The red curve is pretty much the same as blue one, just as following
$$
C_{\text{bull}} = -\frac{(K_2 - K_1)}{2} + (S_T - K_1)_+ - (S_T - K_2)_+
$$